# How to mount and unmount devices remotely from a web service

Tags: apache-2.2, mount

Don't ask me why, but I have to find a way to **allow the Apache user `www-data` to mount and unmount devices** at run-time on the host system. Such devices are, for example, external USB drives on `/dev/sdaXY` formatted with NTFS filesystem.

I'm running the web service on a Debian machine using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3. When I try to run the `mount` command via PHP's `exec()` I obviously have these error message:

```
exec('mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb_flash');
// -> mount: only root can do that

exec('sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb_flash');
// -> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

exec('sudo -n mount /dev/sda1 /media/usb_flash');
// -> sudo: sorry, a password is required to run sudo
```

I'm aware only root can do that (in fact, from SSH, I always need `sudo` when mounting) and that `www-data` cannot be a *sudoer*. But I'm sure there's a way, a workaround, to make my task possible. I don't know where to start looking at: Googling my question is useless, I bet this is not a common scenario.

Comment: Why can www-data not use sudo?

Comment: See the PHP code I posted. Running `sudo` from PHP gives me *sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified* error.

Comment: OK, but that's not a user-specific problem (as your wording implies).

Comment: @HaukeLaging May be. If so, what's the problem if not related to www-data? I tried also `sudo -n`, I'm updating my question.

Comment: I know you said not to ask, but....why????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using [`pmount`](http://packages.debian.org/it/sid/pmount). After I found this tool, it looked the simplest solution to me (no `sudoers` edits, no `fstab` stuff, nothing).

> **`pmount` - mount arbitrary hotpluggable devices as normal user**
>   `pmount`  ("policy mount") is a wrapper around the standard `mount` program
>         which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a  match-ing /etc/fstab entry.

As the manual says, on Debian the  permission  to  execute  `pmount`  is restricted to members of the system group `plugdev`. I had to run the following command once vis SSH, to add Apache usar to the `plugdev` group:

```
sudo adduser www-data plugdev
```

I restarted Apache, and now I can mount and unmount my USB drives from PHP without `sudo`:

```
exec('pmount /dev/sda1 usb_flash'); // Mounted on /media/usb_flash
exec('ls -al /media/usb_flash'); // List files, owned by www-data:600
exec('pumount usb_flash'); // Unmounted
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try the option requiretty in sudoers.
2. An alternative is to run sudo within screen.
3. If the mount points are static (and there is no risk that other users do harm with this) you may create an fstab entry for each of these mounts with the option `user`.

Comment: Tell me more about the `/etc/fstab` solution. I'm reading `man fstab`, but it's quite a mess for me.

Comment: You need not read the whole file, ist about the user option only. But `man 8 mount` is more extensive about that: "Normally,  only  the  superuser  can mount filesystems.  However, when fstab contains the user option on a line, anybody can mount the corresponding system."

Comment: Unfortunately *Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more information at
<http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged>*

Comment: @lorenzo-s Would have made sense to mention NTFS in the question. Go for sudo then.

Comment: I solved in a simpler way today. See my self-answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `setuid` flag may do the trick: create script that mounts your drive, own it by *root*, set the `setuid` flag on it and call this script from apache..

You can set required permissions(setuid and exec) with this command:

```
chmod 4711 <your/script>
```

where the first *4* is the setuid...

see setuid wiki for further reference.

Comment: SUID does not work with scripts.